# <script src="..."> is not working

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

`<script src="...">` is not working.
I am doing a project using maps' API, and I have used GoogleMap API before, but for my needs same API by Yandex is better. But when I am trying to do "srcipt src" command it is not totally working. I can past code of API in my index page, but I suppose for future editing separated file is better, but it is not working :(

There is my index.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Примеры. Добавление на карту большо числа объектов</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- Если вы используете API локально, то в URL ресурса необходимо указывать протокол в стандартном виде (http://...)-->
    <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//yandex.st/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/javascripts/map/object_manager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and object_manager.js

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });
```

I will be great if you help me, because pretty same code for GoogleMap API is working, but for YandexMap API it doesn't.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: you couldn't include app scripts that way. You should read about Rails Assets pipeline [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) take time to reading this

Comment: @gingray hmm, okay I will read, but why Google API is working this way? And thank you for help

Comment: @epascarello there are no errors in console

Comment: @Yomud check plz in web console you probably should see an error that script object_manager.js not found. If everything fine (it can be fine on ur local machine but in production environment you will got error) put ur javascript code in $(document).ready(function(){}); section

Comment: @gingray there is no such error after I start my server, and after rake test there was no errors with object_manager.js too. And, sorry, I am newbie in js, what should I do there "put ur javascript code in $(document).ready(function(){}); section". 

Update. Заметил что вы русский, может тогда на русском? Не надеюсь даже что вы решите за меня всю мою проблему, но надеюсь на небольшое толчок в нужном направлении.

Comment: @Yomud не лебези, в чем именно твоя проблема, первое это тебе нужно правильно подключить assets'ы использую assets pipeline, второе если ты вставляешь js на страницу у тебя все работает, а выносишь в файл не работает. Значит либо файл не подключен, либо код выполняется раньше чем все что нужно загружено.

Comment: @Yomud , тогда тебе следует подклчить JQuery и положить свой код в $(document).ready. Перечислил самые очевидные для меня причины, возможно проблема совершенно в другом, если совсем зеленый не берись за это возьми что-то более простое и вернись снова к этой задаче уже более опытным.

Comment: @gingray, окей, спасибо.